# accessoryTypeCheckmark dissapears when UITableViewCell is hidden

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm creating a function to keep track on deadlines. When you select a row in the deadline table view I change the accessoryType to Checkmark. This works perfectly with this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    Cell *selectedCell = (Cell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];

    if (selectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        [Deadline setDone: TRUE onIndex:indexPath.row];
        selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    } else {
        [Deadline setDone: FALSE onIndex:indexPath.row];
        selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated: YES];
}
```

The problem occurs when you have selected a table cell and the scrolled so it dissappears, when it appears again the accessoryType is None again.

My code for deciding accessoryType in cellForRowAtIndexPath is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    Deadline *d = [self.arrDeadlines objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    Cell *currCell = (Cell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (currCell == nil) 
    {
        UIViewController *c = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Cell" bundle:nil];
        currCell = (Cell *)c.view;
        [c release];        
    }

    currCell.lblTitle.text = d.name;    

    currCell.accessoryType = d.done == TRUE ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    return currCell;
}
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: 1) What value is returned by deadline.done after scroll back was done? 2) Show more code of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. How do you manage cell's dequeueing?

Comment: 1) It's always the same even if i select the cell and then deselect the cell, because I can't run the [tableView reloadData]. 2) Source code is updated above!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not use a TableViewCell to keep data.
This is where your dataSource is for, the TableViewCell is just a visible representation of the data in your dataSource.

Since cell are reused after they are no longer displayed all data gets reset.

Thus in your UItableViewDataSoucre you should check whether a task is done and set the accessoryType yo the checkmark.

So add an NSLog in the cellForIndexPath method and check whether the done boolean is really set.

Comment: After I've updated the datasource in my did didSelectRowAtIndexPath method I need to reload the datasource in order to know if a row's value has been updated, correct? Because now, if I select a row so the checkmark shows, then scroll so the cell doesn't show, then scroll back the checkmark is gone! This is because I haven't reloaded the data source? I don't really understand your answer I'm afraid.

Comment: You should reload your datasource if it's op copy of the data. Which it looks to be, the arrDeadlines looks like an array which is probably a copy of the array where you set the is done state.

Comment: You are so right. I made a copy in my viewDidLoad as I've always have before, I've never worked with changing accessoryTypes. Now I use [Deadline getDeadlines] which allocs an array with my items. What do you think: should I autorelease the array from the getDeadlines method and then use [[Deadline getDeadlines] retain] or how would you do? Thank you for solving my problem!

Comment: It's good practice to autorelease object that a method creates but is not owning. If you datasource is using properties, with (nonatomic, retain), then you should be fine.